# How to add forms for model dynamically and save it at controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add dynamically forms for models with javascript, and after that send all the forms in one single call with the submit button.
This is what I got on javascript:

```
var addButton = '<div class="form-group row">' +
                '<label class="string optional col-2 col-form-label" for="quiz_result_title">Title</label>' +
                '<div class="col-10">' +
                 '   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="quiz_result[title]" id="quiz_result_title" />' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="form-group row">'+
                '<label class="text optional col-2 col-form-label" for="quiz_result_description">Description</label>' +
                '<div class="col-10">' +
                 '   <input class="form-control" type="text" name="quiz_result[description]" id="quiz_result_description" />' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
function add_result () {
$("#quiz-result-forms").append(addButton);
```

}

This is my ruby code and html

```
<%= simple_form_for :quiz_results do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs" id="quiz-result-forms">
        <div class="form-group row">
              <%=  f.label :title, class: "col-2 col-form-label"  %>
            <div class="col-10">
                <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <%=  f.label :description, class: "col-2 col-form-label"  %>
        <div class="col-10">
            <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="add_result()" > ADD QUIZ RESULT</button>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, class: "pull-right"%>
    </div>
```

Currently this adds the fields but when I click Submit the data is overwrite, and only data for one model is sent.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cgMGVg/07yhBFvcU3jWjJfUOcy5YkBFXPSG+oPKxiLxUF7ZvTGmZlCakWkjpWR01WQ1AqDAb+5fzL+wR8KNo2A==", "quiz_result"=>{"title"=>"asdadakjdkaj"}, "commit"=>"Create Quiz result"}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is add forms for new objects and saved in a single call at Controller (I'm not using nested forms). Thanks in advance

Comment: in your params you have `"quiz_result"=>{"title"=>"asdadakjdkaj"}` while in your form `<%= simple_form_for :quiz_results do |f| %>`

if you want to show more then one field you will need to have a collection of `quiz_result` named `quiz_results`

Comment: How can I achieve that? I don't have a parent model for doing something like `parent.quiz_results.build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your params you have `"quiz_result"=>{"title"=>"asdadakjdkaj"}` while in your form `<%= simple_form_for :quiz_results do |f| %>`

if you want to show more then one field you will need to have a collection of `quiz_result` named `quiz_results`

If you want to have one more field you will need to add an object to the `quiz_results` collection

You can do this by re-executing the action and re-rendering the form **synchronously** or re-executing the action and just adding the field with javascript **asynchronously**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Your controller will need strong params declaration for the correct object, not `params.require(:quiz_result).permit!` but `params.require(:quiz_results).premit!`

While this should be in your controller new action.

I would do like this

model `quiz has_many :results`

Then I would use nested attributes like hear

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

In the form show my `@quiz` model and display the `nested attributes`

In the action you can add more more `nested object`
    def new
          @quiz.results.build
    end

Comment: Thanks for the explanation